# Attr_accessor use table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise, attr-accessor

Hi i have a problem with "attr_accessor" in rails 4

I have a model with many associations and when I use attr_accessor I put the field_name but with my association i have many table with the same field name.

For exemple

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :agent
    has_one :language
    attr_accessor :code
end
```

But i have a field :code in agent table and in language table.
I'm trying to find a solution on internet but without success

Is there a way to specify the table name ?

Comment: do you want your attr `:code` to set `code` of  `User`, `Agent` or `Language`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these way to get model speicific `code` from `user` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :agent
    has_one :language
    delegate :code, to: :agent, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
    delegate :code, to: :language, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

As an example:

Now you can access it `User.first.agent_code` for `agent` model Also you can access it `User.first.language_code` for `language` model

You can access the specific `code` by specific model wise

Answer (score -1):

To specify table name expicitly use

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "table_name"
end
```